# How to hide (cover) all button when an action is not complete

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I have keyboard is showing on screen and a Reveal menu Button.

When I tap menu Button, the reveal tableView is shown but keyboard is not hidden.

I want to cover menu Button (can not tap button) if keyboard is showing, it is like UIAlertViewController or like UIActivityViewController, you can not make another action before the alert or activity is completed.

I will add an hide keyboard button to keyboard, but user have to tap this button before tap the reveal menu button.

Comment: Not sure of the layout here,  but you could attach uiviews to the keyboard to block things out, if it is a matter of interaction, you could just turn off user interaction on the master view until the keyboard is dismissed

Comment: Try making sure that you tableview items are not editable in the storyboard.  That should prevent the keyboard being displayed as the text will not be allowed to be edited.  Also just to be clear the keyboard is not already showing? It shows up after clicking on the menu button?

Comment: I can not add self.view.endEditing(true) to button action. It will make app crash because this menu button action was revealToggle(_:)

Answer (score 1):

No need to complicate this issue, you could simply create a `notifier` for your keyboard to handle the interaction for your keyboard.

1: Add these rows in your `viewDidLoad` function

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

2: Add these functions to enable/disable user interaction for your button

```
func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}

func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

To hide the keyboard `self.view.endEditing(true)`.